# Squid Acl rule question

Tags: squid, access-control-list

In squid.conf, there are directives for safe ports and ssl ports:

```
acl safe_ports (list of ports)
acl ssl_port 443
```

then:

```
http_access deny !safe_ports
http_access deny !ssl_port
```

My question is: why the default for http_access is deny !safe_ports and !ssl_port, why not http_access allow safe_ports or http_access allow ssl_port ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do something like:

```
http_access allow safe_ports
```

Then all your ports will be open unless you add a directive after it to deny every port access:

```
http_access deny unsafe_ports
```

where unsafe_ports is exactly !safe_ports, but it is much easier to define a list of safe ports, than a list of unsafe ports, since the later has almost 65536 entries.

Then it is a lot easier and probably more efficient to do

```
http_access deny !safe_ports
```